# How do I get my old firefox profile to run in snap environments of re-installations/other users on my machine?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, profile, snap

My ambition is to reinstall my system and then, in the fresh installation, restore the home-folder of my current main-user from its backup created with borg.

But before I boot the live USB stick, format the drive to commence this, I thought that I first wanted to make sure that I will be able to properly access my firefox profile as well as my mail profiles in thunderbird.

In preparation I created a new user, let's call it `user2` in possession of its' own `/home/`-folder and set up the file permissions between `main-user` and `user2` such that I can create backups through the `user2`-account into that user's `home`-folder of files and folders owned by my actual `main-user`-account. (because they both are in group `borg` and `chown -R 750 ...` and `chown -R 770 ...` respectively)

But NOW to solutions for my actual problem.

```
My approach was to simply try to copy the firefox profile folder in `/home/main-user/firefox/current/` to `/home/user1/firefox/current/` with `rsync` and adjust the `profile.ini` file accordingly.
```

This doesn't work with the sandboxing of the `/snap`-directory very well obviously !

Either snapd seems to prevent these sort of things as the folder is only a `SquashFS` mountpoint for stuff that is actually maintained in `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/`

Through issuing `readlink /home/main-user/snap/firefox/current` I found out that the firefox version in `current` points to the `3779`-Version and thus probably either to `/home/main-user/snap/firefox/3779` or to `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_3779.snap` (as mount source or something?)

Could you please tell me how I properly get my current firefox profile to work in another snap sandbox / mounted package either after re-installation or simply because I want in another user's `/home/userX/snap/` directory ?

Big Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the old install. Create a Mozilla account, synchronize your Data. Reinstall your system then sign in firefox and synchronize.

[Firefox browser sync](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/features/sync/)

> when you switch from your desktop computer to your mobile phone to your tablet. Firefox lets you see your bookmarks, your browsing history, your saved passwords and more, no matter which device you’re using.

---

Installed Firefox through snap store your profile under: `$HOME/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/`, it has `name.default` name. back-up your file.

In the new installation run `firefox --ProfileManager` >> Create profile >> next >> choose folder >> choose the old profile, then validate.

Comment: Hello

is this the only solution with snap? Or just the quick Browser data as  a Service (BdaaS) solution compared to the actual solution with snap?

Comment: @vonspotz Hi! It is the easiest why to migrate firefox profile. You can try it in a live install.

Comment: @vonspotz I will give you an answer with snap.